# Can an SVG inherit its size from the parent element?

Tags: css, svg, vuetify.js

I'm trying to to switch a Vue/Vuetify app from using the webfont for Material Design Icons to [use SVG icons instead](https://dev.materialdesignicons.com/getting-started).

When using the webfont, an example of a heading that contains an icon is

```html
<template>
  <h1>
    <v-icon>mdi-format-list-bulleted</v-icon>
    My Heading
  </h1>
</template>
```

The height of the icon automatically matches the heading because the `<i>` element that is generated for the icon has CSS properties

```
font-size: inherit;
color: inherit;
```

After switching to SVG icons, an example of a heading that contains an icon is

```html
<template>
  <h1>
    <v-icon>{{ iconPath }}</v-icon>
    My Heading
  </h1>
</template>

<script>
  import { mdiFormatListBulleted } from '@mdi/js'

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      iconPath: mdiFormatListBulleted
    })
  }
</script>
```

This generates the following markup instead:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img"
    aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon__svg">
    <!-- path element omitted -->
</svg>
```

the CSS class has the following properties

```
.v-icon__svg {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    fill: currentColor;
}
```

The fixed icon height of 24px means that the SVG icon doesn't match the heading's height.

Although the `<v-icon>` component provides a number of props that I can use to change the icon's size, e.g. `size`, `large`, `small`, these will fix the size to a specific value, rather than inheriting the size from the parent element.

Is there a way for an SVG to inherit it's size from it's parent element? More specifically, I want the SVG height and width to be the same as the parent element's height.

### Demo

I've created a [demo of what happens when you use SVG icons](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-vuetify-global-scss-vars-vu2yqz?file=src/views/Home.vue). It takes about 30 seconds for it to load, and you may need to disable 3rd party cookies for it to work.

Comment: *It takes about 30 seconds for it to load, and you may need to disable 3rd party cookies for it to work.* --> no, you are required to create a minimal code for us where we don't need to wait 30s and do complex manipulation

Comment: Try `.v-icon__svg { height: 100%; width: auto; }`

Comment: @RenevanderLende i tried this, but it didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the height of the SVG to one of the [relative units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#relative_length_units_based_on_font) it will match the font-size of the context. You can combine this with [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) if necessary.

```css
h1,h2 {
  color: navy;
}

.height-ch {
    height: 1ch;
    fill: currentColor;
}

.height-em {
    height: 1em;
    fill: currentColor;
}

.height-rem {
    height: 1rem;
    fill: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<h1>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img"
    aria-hidden="true" class="height-em">
    <path d="M 0 0 L 24 0 L 24 24 L 0 24 Z" />
</svg>
Heading em
</h1>
<h2>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img"
    aria-hidden="true" class="height-em">
    <path d="M 0 0 L 24 0 L 24 24 L 0 24 Z" />
</svg>
Heading em
</h2>
<h2>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img"
    aria-hidden="true" class="height-ch">
    <path d="M 0 0 L 24 0 L 24 24 L 0 24 Z" />
</svg>
Heading ch
</h2>
<h2>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img"
    aria-hidden="true" class="height-rem">
    <path d="M 0 0 L 24 0 L 24 24 L 0 24 Z" />
</svg>
Heading rem
</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm wondering why you say this doesn't really work for `rem`, because based on the examples, it looks like this is the only unit that it _does_ work for. In the case of `em` the icon is too tall when parented by a `h2` and in the case of `ch`, the icon is too small when parented by `h2`.

Comment: @Dónal I'm not that experienced with `rem`, but as you say it is the one that looks best. Maybe I should just remove my comment about the `rem`.